# Object(...) is not a function at angular-bootstrap-md.js:10351

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm installed angular-bootstrap-md to use this modules:

```
import { WavesModule, TableModule, IconsModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
```

But receive this error:

```
angular-bootstrap-md.js:10351 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at angular-bootstrap-md.js:10351
    at Module../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/fesm5/angular-bootstrap-md.js (angular-bootstrap-md.js:10353)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/admin/admin.module.ts (admin.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.1.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

For HTML and TS file I use example from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/tables/sort/

Still can't find how to fix this problem...

Answer (score 2):

You probably install this library wrong here you have an example how to install it:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/

The problem is this library works not only for Angular but other frameworks and you can install it in different ways.

So you should install it using `ng add angular-bootstrap-md` command.

Comment: Same problem https://i.imgur.com/4W9eDyh.png I reinstaled angular/core, but not fix the problem.

Comment: Try to install it like on `quick-start` by `ng add` command or by your self changing files.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue , try

> ng add angular-bootstrap-md@6.3.0

I got this issue on version 8 but i found that it works only on angular 8 
downgrading to 6.3.0 solve the issue